# What (if anything) is the inspiration behind A’ctelios Salash in "A Wandering Inn"?

Tags: inspiration, reference, the-wandering-inn

[A’ctelios Salash, the Carven City, Tombhome, the Shield Kingdom which Rots](https://thewanderinginn.fandom.com/wiki/A%E2%80%99ctelios_Salash) - I think I've seen the concept of a rotten giant being eaten and corrupting those who eat it. But I'm not sure where!

Does anyone know if there's a specific reference or inspiration for the city and its curse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[I asked about this on the subreddit](https://reddit.com/r/WanderingInn/s/0DS6btgn8r). No official answer from the author, but apparently this comes up early often in these are the main theories.

A number of people pointed out to the general description of the humanoid monstrosities in Lovecraft's works. More aptly, though:

> it's sort of similar to the lore of [old phyrexia](https://mtg.fandom.com/wiki/Phyrexia) (from Magic the Gathering) minus all the machine/artificing influences. in that there is the corpse of a plane sized old machine/god that has corrupting oil/blood. its 9 layers sit dormant and empty until a guy called yogmoth occupies it and uses the blood for eugenics/cybernetic/magitech experiments on his people the Thran. This of course corrupts them and kicks off the whole first Phyrexian invasion. This is all almost literally the genesis of Magic's plot.

Then, of course, there was the one wag who pointed out the example of *James and the Giant Peach* where a human consumes the flesh of that one within which he lives, and is horribly corrupted into a claymation version of himself.

Answer (score 0):

I also found this answer in one of the threads:

https://www.reddit.com/r/WanderingInn/comments/16clmc1/comment/k1b3bga/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

> Flos had indeed told her about the horrible city carved out of a dead
> thing. Teres thought it sounded a bit like Cthulhu or something,
> but—it was probably not. Right? Trey had promised to take videos,
> anyways. She was also a tiny bit worried about him since he could be a
> right idiot. But the King of Destruction was reassuringly relaxed.

From https://wanderinginn.com/2020/02/26/7-10-k/

---

Also reminds me a bit of the Giant from the Ender's Game book "Mind Game" - the one which Ender kills by digging into its eye:

https://enderverse.fandom.com/wiki/Mind_Game